# Java JUnit: Testing a readFile method using a temporary file, FileUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, fileutils

I have a problem with java, it gives me an error inside my code when I run a test for writing to a file.
It isn’t finished yet but in the test I create a sort of ‘mock’ temporary file where I write a string.
**as my code shouldn't be allowed to read strings

```
@Rule
       public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
     @Test
       public void testWrite() throws IOException {
         // Create a temporary file.
         final File tempFile = tempFolder.newFile("tempFile.txt");
       
         // Write something to it.
         FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tempFile, "hello world");
       }
```

Unfortunately the FileUtils seems not to be recognised.
Relating to that the import:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

Isn’t recognised either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have added the apache commons jar into your classpath before trying to import FileUtils.